# is there a way to make VideoView keep playing in background on Android app?

Tags: android, video, streaming, html5-video, android-videoview

I'm currently using VideoView to play video from URL (Streaming..),
when i press home the video stops..

is there a way to make it keep playing?

Whats the best way to make a video keep running in background?

Thanks in advance,
Amitos80

Comment: Why to do so? User wont see a video when he is not in your app. You want to have audio playback unstopped?

Comment: Yes, I want to have the audio playback still running. I think the only way is to hold VideoView inside the activity and to bind to a service that only plays the audio.. I'm thinking the sync between the two would be a tricky. any ideas?

Comment: Hi amitos80, how do you solve this problem?

Comment: I found a way to do that using Titanium Appcelerator. using the android sdk I couldnt find a way to achive that. Another solution is to play music and video separately and sync them, for example in onResume - but its very tricky.. goodluck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MediaPlayer instead of VideoView.

```
m = new MediaPlayer();
m.setDatasource(url);
m.prepare();
m.start();
```